# Automating cell movement preferably using if/when style conditions

Tags: vba, excel

**What I am trying to achieve:**

[image: What I am trying to achieve.]

I want to fully automate the process of cleaning up exported data. 
I want to move the data in the overflow rows into their prospective column. I have tried the following code in VBA. (This is trying to identify the @ symbol in the emails and respectively move all email address two places to the right).

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim D As Range, r As Range
    Set D = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("D:D"))

    For Each r In D
        If Left(r.Text, 2) = "@" Then
            r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
            r.Clear
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Once the data is in the correct column I need to automate the movement into the correct row. I can easily have them shift up but if one contact doesn't have an email address (as an example) then the emails will be in the wrong rows when they shift up.

Comment: From the image it seems source for email address is column D and target is column E. Is this going to be constant? It would be great if you can say what all things will remain as such for multiple data. For example will there be a single data entry in the address column for all records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim rw As Range,  currRow As Long
    Dim v, col As Long

    Set rw = ActiveSheet.Rows(2)
    currRow = 0

    Do While rw.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        If rw.Cells(2).Value <> "" Then
            currRow = rw.Row 'moving "overflow" items to this row...
        Else
            If currRow > 0 Then
                v = rw.Cells(4).Value
                col = 0

                'Figure out which column item should be moved to...
                ' "[" is a special character to "Like", so needs to be
                '      enclosed in "[]"
                If v Like "[[]M]:*" Then
                    col = 8
                ElseIf v Like "[[]E]:*" Then
                    col = 6
                ElseIf v Like "[[]H]:*" Then
                    col = 7
                ElseIf v Like "[[]Address]:*" Then
                    col = 9
                End If
                'Got a pattern match, so move this item...
                'Change ".Copy" to ".Cut" when you're done testing...

                If col > 0 Then rw.Cells(4).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(currRow, col)
            End If
        End If
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0) 'next row....
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you this is perfect. I'll study this answer to make sure I know how it works and can replicate on my own.